# Proper use of various derivative and partial derivative notations

Tags: derivatives, notation, partial-derivative

I think I have seen all of these notations and more used

for derivatives:

$\dot f(x)$,

$f'(x)$,

$f_x(x)$,

$df(x)/dx$,

$D f(x)$

and for partial derivatives:

$\partial f(x,y)/\partial x$,

$\partial_x f(x,y)$,

$f_x(x,y)$,

$D_x f(x,y)$

and the corresponding notations used for higher order derivatives

for derivatives:

$f''(x)$,

$f_{xx}(x)$,

$d^2f(x)/dx^2$,

$D^2_x f(x)$

and for partial derivatives:

$\partial^2 f(x,y)/\partial x^2$,

$\partial_{xx} f(x,y)$,

$f_{xx}(x,y)$,

$D_{xx} f(x,y)$

I also think I have seen many of these used without the function argument, e.g $f'$ or $f_x$.

**My question is:** *Is there an accepted proper usage for these derivative notations.*

Any links or references would be appreciated.

See also
[Why are there so many notations for differentiation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/713521/147776)

Comment: You will find that all notations will be used in different contexts. There is no "right notation".

Comment: Mathematically, they all mean the same thing. The difference in usage is historical, or for the sake of convenience, abbreviation or emphasis of certain properties or characteristics.

Comment: Is it ok to mix them up in a single piece of work, e.g. a derivation?

Comment: Generally you just want to be consistent with your notation. And depending on what subject you are studying/researching, it’s helpful to use the notation common to the literature. For example, $f_x(x)$ would show up more in a statistical context to refer to the fact that this is the derivative of the distribution function of $x$. $f’(x)$ would be more of a general calculus setting and $df(x)/dx$ would be consistent throughout a differential equations context. Different professors also have different preferences for different subjects, so just be consistent with what you choose.

Answer (score 2):

In Korner's *A Companion to Analysis: A Second First and First Second Course in Analysis* (pp. 396-397), he relates Felix Klein's complaint that

> "There are a great many symbols used for each of the vector operations and, so far, it has proved impossible to produce a generally accepted notation. A commission was set up for this purpose at a scientific meeting in Kassel ($1903$). However, its members were not even able to come to a complete agreement among themselves. None the less, since their intentions were good, each member was willing to meet the others part way and the result was to bring three new notations into existence!"

This helped me realise that they are each used for a good reason, so you should make sure you are comfortable working between them as necessary. For the purposes of the reader though, it would be kind to stick to one notation at a time.